# Add divider | between menus

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a separator between my navigation menu(header).

So basically make it A|B|C

I tried to add this code:

This is an edit:

So my snip, from where the title and url are retrieved looks like this:

```html
<li class="dropdown{% if link.active %} selected{% endif %}{% if submenu_type == 'menu_two_columns' %} tt-megamenu-col-02{% elsif submenu_type == 'megamenu' %} megamenu{% else %} tt-megamenu-col-01{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>

  <a href="{{ link.url }}" class=".link">{{ link.title }}</a>
```

And I added this code in my theme.css

```html
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.link:before {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.link:first-child:before {
  content: '';
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #000;
}
```

However, I am not getting the |

Comment: Please, add the HTML code as well.

Comment: please show me what are you doing in code or provide a link so we can understand easily

Comment: Without seeing your html, im guessing this line is squishing the text:  width: 1px; But yeah, lets see your html and go from there.

Comment: I added more of the html. I'm using shopify, so it's a little bit new to me, and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Remove the `width: 1px;` from `.link` and you should see the text again.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

I've taken your exact updated `CSS` and placed a few `.link` anchors inside a `nav` container. You can see the generated content (separator bar) working as you've styled. The only thing I've changed, which doesn't affect the render, is replacing `content: ''` with `content: none`.

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.link:before {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.link:first-child:before {
  content: none;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="link">A</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">B</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">C</a>
</nav>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4rb93a2/)

---

Here's an example for you using a pseudo class to create the bar separator (`|`) in CSS content. This is the preferred way to handle details like this because you have more control over the content styling and positioning. I'm also using CSS negation to *not* add the separator after the last child. To vertically center the generated content, I've used `top: 50%` and a `transform: translateY(-50%)` to account for half the height of the actual separator.

```css
.link{
   margin: 0 5px;
   background-color: #DDD;
   position: relative;
}

.link:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-right: 2px solid #000;  
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="link">A</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">B</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">C</a>
</nav>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ypcnude/)

Comment: I have updates my question with more details, can you please have a look ?

Comment: @UnFashioner And I've updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Hey Andy, let me give it a try. I think i tried with the updated answer, but wasn't getting anywhere. I'm starting to think it's something to do with my theme..but let's see.

Comment: @UnFashioner Your problem is in the `HTML`. `class=".link"` should be `class="link"` (no period).

Comment: I made an error typing it, in the file itself it's actually without a dot. I just tried it and no good...I am just amazed. I updated my initial post with the code that is above ahref if you can take a look, could that be causing it ?

Comment: You should look at is the *generated source*. Please include that above.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify ? The theme is installed so any changes that are made are reflected live.

Answer (score 0):

you set width:1px to link class so content of that class is not appears, just replace your css code

```
.link{
   height: 40px;
   width: 1px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #DDD;
   border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

with

```
.link{
   height: 40px;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #DDD;
   border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:0 15px;
}
li:first-child{
  padding-left:0;
}
li:last-child{
  padding-right:0;
}
li:not(:last-child):after{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid #000; 
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  right:0;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your border on the left of each link:

```
.link {
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Then add a CSS rule that cancels that border on the first link using the `first-child` selector:

```
.link:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

It's important your links are behaving like links, taking up enough space, etc. I used my own approach here, feel free to take what you like.

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.link:before {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.link:first-child:before {
  content: '';
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="/home" class="link">Home</a>
  <a href="/about" class="link">About</a>
  <a href="/contact" class="link">Contact</a>
  <a href="/blog" class="link">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be the only one working. However, I would like to separate them by | and not put them in boxes like that.

Comment: I personally think this looks a little odd but I have updated the example to use "|" instead of a border. Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't work...there is no |, i give up on this stupid little thing. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Horizontal rule between tags

```css
.menu {
      background: #ddd;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .link {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      padding: 0 30px;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #ddd;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
      
    }
    hr{
    margin:0px;
    color:blue;
    }
    
    .link:first-child {
      border-left: none;
    }
    
    .link:hover {
      background-color: #aaa;
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
      <a href="/home" class="link">Home</a><hr>
      <a href="/about" class="link">About</a><hr>
      <a href="/contact" class="link">Contact</a><hr>
      <a href="/blog" class="link">Blog</a><hr>
    </nav>
```

---

Whats the catcher just place a hr tag between each link and you get the line. hr means horizontal line but since the display is set to inline block and the height is set it can be used as a vertical line

Comment: There is no |. My menu page is still A B C instead of A|B|C

Comment: Did you set the css of the hr tags make the width about 1px and height to whatever height is required

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I added the css code and then used <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="link">{{ link.title }}</a> to call it. If i use <nav. my menu goes from A  B  C to ABC

Comment: Set the color or try setting the margin did the <hr> tag add an effect

Comment: No, i changed the color and it did not appear, I tried adding <hr> tag but that did not work either.